# Whys is ["text"] == ["text"] false?

Tags: javascript, syntax, expression, ecmascript-5

Why does the expression `["text"] == ["text"]` evaluate to `false` in JavaScript?

I intuitively expected it to be true, since the two arrays are identical. Is the JS engine comparing references to two different objects, and thus returning false, instead of comparing the contents of the arrays?

Comment: js never compares contents of arrays

Comment: They are two different objects that just happen to have the same properties.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have created two different arrays and JavaScript is comparing their references, not their content.

```js
const array = [1, 2, 3];

// evaluates to true
console.log(array === array);

// evaluates to false
console.log([1, 2, 3] === [1, 2, 3]);
```

Here is a very well constructed answer on comparing the contents of arrays: [How to compare arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript)

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was wondering, and the link you provided is very helpful for the code I'm writing.